# Call Microsoft Bot Framework bot from Web Client without hosting on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I need to establish communication b/w a simple Microsoft Bot Framework bot and a web client (HTML, CSS & JavaScript, jQuery)

I see there are ways to do this using WebChat, DirectLine API, but I don't want to use any Azure services like Bot Registrations Service or App Service for getting the channels but instead I would like to use plain JavaScript to invoke the bot as it is just a Web API application there must be a way.

I tried a simple jQuery ajax call, it calls the server but it fails soon after

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post('http://localhost:3979/api/messages', {
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
      "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
  }).fail(function(error) {
    debugger;
  }).done(function(response) {
    debugger;
  });
});
```

It seems I need to form the activity object completely https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#activity-object but how can I get all the property values

Could anyone tell me whether it's possible and how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of at least [directline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) is required for your bot to work (one of these is included in the emulator which is why it is able to handle conversations and activities for you), and hosting your bot via a free bot registration channel on azure will also handle this for you.

One example of an unofficial implementation of directline that does not require Azure is [offline directline](https://github.com/ryanvolum/offline_dl), but if you create an implementation that handles conversation IDs along with the other required activity parameters this will also work.